# Conditions under which an arbitrary set $A$ satisfies $\mathscr{P}(\bigcup A) \subseteq A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm working within the axioms of $\mathbf{ZF}$, and we're only considering sets made out of the empty set, $\emptyset$. One could try out simple cases, and see that $  \{\emptyset\}$ and $ \{ \emptyset, \{\emptyset \}\}$ satisfy $\mathscr{P}(\bigcup A) \subseteq A$.

But how could one prove that these are the only cases, and no other sets fulfill the condition?

**Addendum**: Is there a general method to find special cases of sets which satisfy a certain subset relation, say $\mathscr{P}(A\cup B) \subseteq \mathscr{P}(A) \cup \mathscr{P}(B)$, and prove that no other sets fit the bill? Of course, $\mathscr{P}(A)  \cup \mathscr{P}(B) \subseteq \mathscr{P}(A \cup B)$ in general, but I'm considering only subset relations which don't hold generally.  One could guess and check, but I'm thinking about a systematic procedure to find these sets.

Comment: How can $A$ be both of those non-equal sets?

Comment: Corrected, thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't it be corrected when you are talking about the powerset too?

Comment: In general you have $\mathcal{P}(\bigcup A) \supseteq A$, so $\mathcal{P}(\bigcup A) \subseteq A$ is equivalent to $A = \mathcal{P}(\bigcup A)$.

Comment: @Maxis Jaisi: Waht about $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}, \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}$